# Is there an optimal UD code not PF?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I'm learning the coding theory and referring the textbook "Codes: An Introduction to Information Communication and Cryptography" written by Norman L. Biggs. In Section 3.7, the author proved that a Huffman code is optimal. I think (from his proof with binary case) he meant that code is optimal on the PF (prefix-free) sense. Is my thought true?

Since he defined "optimal" on UD (uniquely-decodable) codes, I want to know whether there is an optimal UD code which is not PF. I tried few examples and I failed.

Thanking you.

Comment: Yes, there are. if you reverse all the codewords of a UD, it will be UD but in most cases not PF. Huffman code is optimal, but there are other codes that are not PF and reach the same expected length.